# Samsung N150 backlight issue

Tags: 11.10, samsung

I have a Samsung N150 Netbook and I try Ubuntu 11.10. In Natty backlight changing does not work at all. In Oneiric it does, but I can only switch between 100% and minimum.

If I boot in battery mode the backligth is "blingking" continously.

How can I fix that?

Comment: This has been answered *so* many times on this website and others. Please run this search. There are two options: use PPA for the `samsung-backlight` package or edit a udev script. Seriously, click this link for more: http://askubuntu.com/search?q=samsung+backlight

Answer (score 2):

I have a Samsung N150 too. I love it.

Add the [Voria repository](https://launchpad.net/~voria/+archive/ppa) to your list of sources and everything will work perfectly.

If you'd rather not do this I wrote a script to change the brightness.

The script is

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ $1 == 'FULL' ];then
    v=99
elif [ $1 -gt 99 ];then
    v=99
elif [ $1 -lt 3 ];then
    v=3
else 
    v=$1
fi

sudo setpci -s 00:02.0 F4.B=$v
```

Save it in your path and run it as

```
sudo brightness x
```

where x is the percentage brightness.

Comment: Oneiric, not Natty. There is no Oneiric Version of the PPA

Comment: You want this fixed in Oneiric, which isn't yet released. Historically Voria repos are updated the same day as release so support for Natty was the same day natty was released. You can try the script for now, but you will have to wait otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a boot loader screen to choose which OS to boot into then it is possible to change the brightness using the keyboard function keys, before loading up Ubuntu. It will default back at the next restart, but it is a simple work round for now.